# iOS Dev Socket based Stream programming with Python- UITableView error

Tags: ios, uitableview, assertion

I am following this tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server#comments

I have reached the end of the header titled **Receiving Messages**.
Even after doing everything the tutorial states, I am receiving this error when entering a username on the first page and pressing the button. I am unsure whether this is a problem with my python server or with the actual iOS code. The python server listens on the standard TCP port 80 using reactor.

> 2013-07-19 17:10:13.450 Chat Client[3505:c07] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _configureCellForDisplay:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2380.17/UITableView.m:5471
>   2013-07-19 17:10:13.451 Chat Client[3505:c07]**  Terminating app due to uncaught exception >'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UITableView dataSource must return a cell from >tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:'
>   ** First throw call stack:
>   (0x1c94012 0x10d1e7e 0x1c93e78 0xb67665 0xcbc1b 0x6040c 0xcba7b 0xd0919 0xd09cf 0xb91bb >0xc9b4b 0x662dd 0x10e56b0 0x2290fc0 0x228533c 0x2285150 0x22030bc 0x2204227 0x22048e2 >0x1c5cafe 0x1c5ca3d 0x1c3a7c2 0x1c39f44 0x1c39e1b 0x1bee7e3 0x1bee668 0x15ffc 0x244d 0x2375)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

I believe the error is to be found in some of this code here:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtInexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ChatCellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSString *s = (NSString *) [messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = s;

    return cell;
}

-(void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {
    NSLog(@"stream event %i", streamEvent);

    switch (streamEvent) {

        case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
            NSLog(@"Stream opened");
            break;

        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:

            if (theStream == inputStream) {

                uint8_t buffer[1024];
                int len;

                while([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {

                    len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
                    if(len>0) {
                        NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

                        if (nil != output) {
                            NSLog(@"server said: %@", output);
                            [self messageReceived:output];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        break;

        case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
            NSLog(@"Can not connect to the host!");
            break;

        case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
            break;

        default:
            NSLog(@"Unknown event");
    }
}
```

Comment: That error is pretty straightforward.  It indicates you are not returning a cell from your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method.  It looks like you are though... so did you set a breakpoint in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: and double check that it is getting called?

Comment: No I have not. Where would I check that it is getting called? I am fairly new to iOS development.

Comment: The initial firing of this event happens when a message is received, as appears in -(void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream in the case "NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:" on [self messageReceived:output];   as the messageReceived method calls [messages addObject:message]; and [self.tView reloadData]; where tView is the table view and messages is an NSMutableArray made for storing the chat messages.